# Combine two selects with different rowcounts and a group by

Tags: mysql

I have a main-table "contracts" with an id (primary-key) and some columns i have to sum together for every row. 
My second table "payments" is in a 1 to n relation to "contracts", for every row in "contracts" there are zero to several rows in "payments".

I can select the "contrats"-table as such:

```
select c.Id, sum(c.field1 + c.field2 + c.field3) as TotalC from contracts c group by c.Id
```

I can select from the "payments"-table like:

```
select p.Id, sum(p.field1) from payments p group by p.Id
```

So c.Id and p.Id are related. Both selects give me one row per contract-ID. But not every contract has a payment. Is it possible to combine those two selects in a sensible way? Or would I be better of getting those two selects in my program and do the comparison outside of sql?

I could use an INNER JOIN like scaisEdge suggested, but
the problem I have with this is:

Result of the select before it is grouped:

```
ID  |  TotalContractSum  |  SinglePayment
22  | 50,00 | 25,00
22  | 50,00 | 30,00
```

Result AFTER grouping (the endresult):

```
22 | 100,00 | 55,00
```

Now the SinglePayment is grouped together as it should be, but the TotalContractSum has doubled, because there were two rows in the payment-table. So in short, the grouping is the problem here.

Comment: if should not use sum on single row: select p.Id, sum(p.field1) from payments p group by p.Id, is same as select p.Id, p.field1 from payments p

Comment: Please provide the structure of both tables. Just to know if there are any relations between these two tables.

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join

```
select c.Id, sum(c.field1 + c.field2 + c.field3) as TotalC ,  sum(p.field1)
from contracts c 
INNER JOIN payments p
ON c.id = p.id
group by c.I
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found similar queries on the internet, but here is the problem.

Comment: eventually update your post and show a sample of data and expected result